# Help me solve my school's rebus!

Tags: rebus

My school just had a Cryptic Hunt and we were given this image:

[image]

We were also given a hint :

> **I don't want to cook anymore**

We were supposed to give back **a word as an answer**.  I wasn't able to answer it, and sadly, they didn't provide us the solution. I'm really curious, does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This sort of puzzle where there is a series of pictures which lead to a word is known as a *rebus*. It may be quite hard to solve if you don't know the answer so there may be quite a few correct answers

Comment: It says "rhino heart" to me. It might be related to your school's mascot, maybe? Hard to say without more context.

Comment: no related to my school at all we tried

Comment: Are we supposed to give a single word or a phrase?

Comment: yes single word

Comment: maybe we need to know the solutions of the other puzzles to solve this one.

Comment: it was the first one i could't solve the first one

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "puzzles [on this site] must not be from active competitions" http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @AE the competition has finished

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil That's fine then. :)

Comment: What school?  Do any of your teachers or classrooms or buildings have the name "Reinhart"?

Comment: Actually, what *country* or active *language*? I think most of us seem to have assumed English, but is that really the case? It could be a rebus word game in a different language an then it becomes quite hard for English speakers to solve....

Comment: @LeppyR64 Or maybe the we are in presence of fans of [Django Reinhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_Reinhardt)!

Comment: How sophisticated were the other rebuses? That would give us a clue. Maybe you can provide one.

Answer (score 8):

This possible answer came to me whilst on a bus:

> Coeliac

Reasoning:

> rye no love - could be gluten intolerance; no love for rye (gluten is found in grains such as rye) and this would most certainly put me off cooking!

Answer (score 1):

> Vegetarian: because you love animals and you don't want to eat them anymore.

Comment: They could've used something more people are likely to eat, like a cow or a chicken, maybe a goat. I don't know that many people who eat Rhino.

Comment: you can cook vegetables aswell